# Converting an HTML table to JSON to pass to an AJAX call for downloading as a CSV

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, csv

I am having to write a reporting system in ASP classic.
The people who wrote the wireframe have no concept of performance/speed/how SQL works and so forth so I have lots of fun just getting the data out of the DB.

However they want to have buttons the users can press to "download" the report to a CSV file.

I could submit the form and re-run the SQL (which takes a long time due to the number of reports shown on one page and their format) - and then just send it to the browser as a file.

OR I was thinking of using JS or jQuery etc to take the desired table of contents, somehow convert that to a JSON object, post that to another page using AJAX and then in that other page take the JSON and decode it into a CSV format which can then be delivered to the user as a file.

I just think this JS approach would be quicker and also if I could make it generic so it could take any table with a class on it e.g "report" and convert that into a JSON object that would be used to create a CSV I could easily re-use this code on the hundreds of reports they have made me write.

Does anyone have an JavsaScript code or jQuery that would take a table in any format (it has a thead with column headers, the a tbody with the main contents) and encode it to a JSON or JS object for posting to another page where I could then de-encode it and pipe it out as a CSV file?

Here is a screen shot of one of their reports,

[image: Just one example of a report format to download]

Comment: While it's an important factor how expensive it is to fetch data from a db, sending the dataset back to the server and downloading again seems to be an undesired overhead.

Comment: Do you display the reports in full in one table, or are those fetched from the server in a paginated manner?

Comment: Let me understand you correctly. All you want is to download the `table` as `.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to the problem could be to already generate the CSV formatted version of the data for each report when the page that displays the given report is requested. (Database is only queried once per report.) Send the data back in the response in the expected format to display it in the table and save the CSV file to a temporary location on the server.

This way you can place a link near the table 'download CSV' which will point to the already existing file. It will avoid having to query the same data twice for one report OR to having to send the same data to a roundtrip between server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't provide a way to save text to a file, so you would still have to do that server-side, i.e. by AJAX as you already suggested.

With jQuery you could do something like this (not tested), and send it via an AJAX request.

```
var headers = [];
$('table.report thead > tr > th').each(function($i, obj) { //or <td> instead of <th>
    headers.push($(obj).text());
});

var data = [];
$('table.report tbody > tr').each(function($i, tr) {
    var row = [];
    $(tr).find('th').each(function($h, td) {
        row[headers[$h]] = td.text();
    });

    data.push(row);
});

var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

However I don't think this is the preferable way, because it's still user-input. I could put some random data in a POST and get a CSV in return.

A better way would be to cache your data you already have, and create a CSV file from the cached data when requested.

Comment: Ok thanks for the ideas. Having the data cached in Session vars when loaded might be the way so I don't have to load it again. I just wanted something generic as each report has different no of columns/rows - some have a totals row other don't and so on. So I wanted a way of just chucking the data into cache (like arrData = objRS.GetRows() to put it in an array) that I could store in a Session and use later on

Comment: Problem with creating a cache of the data is that putting it in a session causes a referential pointer and as there are multiple recordsets when I get to handle the session it says it's empty and I cannot move to the beginning of the recordsets(multiple) - need a way to cache the data (generically), no matter what column headers or rows are in the recordsets