# Creating a copy of a recordset in a Session variable

Tags: session, memory, asp-classic, ado, recordset

This is a follow on from a question I asked here > [Converting an HTML table to JSON to pass to an AJAX call for downloading as a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158618/converting-an-html-table-to-json-to-pass-to-an-ajax-call-for-downloading-as-a-cs)

I have a report page that outputs a number of recordsets as graphs and tables but also buttons to "download as a CSV file" I have a generic function that will take any number of recordsets (as the stored proc returns multiple recordsets) and outputs a CSV so thats fine.

The issue is I want to set the output of my stored proc into a Session("DATA") variable and then create a "copy" of the data in memory so that whenever the "download" button is pressed I can just look for a Session("DATA") variable and output it if it exists.

The problem is that when I set a recordset object to point at the Session it is referential so that once it has looped through all the recordsets outputting them on the page the Session is then empty (or at the end of all the recordsets - so it's an object with no data in it)

How can I Create a "copy" of the recordset instead of a pointer so that the Session always has the full recordset in it e.g

```
Set Session("DATA") = objCon.Execute(strSQL) '* returns multiple recordsets

Set objRS = Session("DATA")

Do While Not objRS.EOF......

'* BUT now when I want to access Session("DATA") it is at the start of all the recordsets and not a spent, EOF of the last recordset due to me looping through objRS
```

I could have a function that loops through the recordsets and makes a duplicate but then that seems like a lot of effort and performance and I thought there must be a way to copy the recordsets for the session somehow without looping through it multiple times.

If I have to create a "Copy" object function then I suppose I will have to but is there not an easier way in ASP CLASSIC to create a copy of an object and not a reference pointer?

Comment: What cursors type are you using in your objCon? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681771(v=vs.85).aspx   If it is adOpenStatic you can move your cursor back to the start e.g. objRS.MoveFirst

Comment: I have a complex data class that supports disconnected recordsets, either returning recordcounts (where the recordset is set to objRecordset.CacheSize  = 20
objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRecordset.LockType  = adLockReadOnly ) -> Obviously I need to move to the first recordset of the multiple recordsets that are outputted not just the first record of one recordset. I am thinking of using JS to copy the table by ID into Excel if i cannot create a COPY of the recordset easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the entire recordset into an array, using `GetRows`:

```vbs
'GetDataSet
'   Returns a table of data based on the supplied SQL statement and connection string.
'Parameters:
'   sqlString (string) - The SQL string to be sent. This can be either a valid SQL string or an Application setting
'                           specified using the '@' prefix (e.g. @GET_USERNAME)
'   connString (string) - The database connection string. Either a valid connection string, an Application setting
'                           (using the '@' prefix, e.g. @CONN_STRING) or an AMC (AppModeConnection string).
'Usage:
'   dataSet = GetDataSet(sqlString, connString)
'Description:
'   This function generates a table of information in a 2 dimensional array.  The first dimension represents the columns
'   and the second the rows.  If an error occurs while the routine is executing the array and the base index (0,0) is set 
'   to C_ERROR, (0,1) to the VBScript error index, and (0,2) to the VBScript error description.
'Notes:
'   Updated this function to take advantage of the AppModeConnection feature.
'Revisions:
'   30/09/2015  1.1     Added facility to allow recovery of Application settings as Query and connection strings using 
'                       '@', (e.g.: ds = GetDataSet("@GET_USER_DETAIL", "@CONN_DATABASE")
'   25/09/2015  1.0     Added AMC support for Classic ASP. The system will test to see if there is a valid connection 
'                       string based on the current application mode and the connection string provided (e.g. if the 
'                       connection string is 'CONN_DATABASE' and the application mode is 'DEV' then the final connection
'                       string will be 'CONN_DATABASE_DEV'. A connection string should be present to cover this.
' < 25/09/2015  0.1     Bug ironed out that prevented closing of the database.
' < 25/09/2015  0.0     Initial version.
function GetDataSet(ByVal sqlString, ByVal connString)
    'Test to see if there's an application connection string first...
    If Left(connString, 1) = "@" Then
        connString = Application(Mid(connString, 2))
    Else
        Dim amc
        amc = AppModeConnection(connString)
        If amc <> "" then connString = amc
    End If
    'Test the SQL string to see if it's stored as an Application setting...
    If Left(sqlString, 1) = "@" Then sqlString = Application(Mid(sqlString, 2))
    'Define the initial output...
    dim rV, rs
    If  (Application("APP_MODE") =  Application("MODE_DEV")  And  Application("DEV_TRAP_ERRORS")) Or _
        (Application("APP_MODE") <> Application("MODE_DEV")) Then On Error Resume Next
        'Define and open the recordset object...
        set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        rs.Open sqlString, connString, 0, 1, 1
        'Initialise an empty value for the containing array...
        redim rV(0,0)
        rV(0,0) = C_NO_DATA
        'Deal with any errors...
        if not rs.EOF and not rs.BOF then
            'Store the data...
            rV = rs.GetRows()
            'Tidy up...
            rs.close
            set rs = nothing
            select case err.number
                case 3021   'No data returned
                    'Do nothing as the initial value will still exist (C_NO_DATA)
                case 0      'No error
                    'Do nothing as data has been returned
                case else
                    redim rV(4,0)
                    rV(C_COL_IDENTIFIER,0) = C_ERROR
                    rV(C_COL_ERROR_ID,0) = err.number
                    rV(C_COL_ERROR_MESSAGE,0) = err.description
                    rV(C_COL_SQL,0) = sqlString
                    rV(C_COL_CONNECTION,0) = "Withheld"
            end select
        end if
    on error goto 0
    'Return the array...
    GetDataSet = rV
end function
```

This is my own in depth version which does some funky stuff with connection strings etc, so feel free to use it, but note that you'll have to set-up the handling for the connection strings etc. Within the code, though, is the core element - the `GetRows`, that you require.

You shouldn't need to set any Session variables, simply process all in the same page, as per [marekful's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34158965/3748030) to your post. You can do this using a simple `For...Next` loop using an array.

To use the function above simply declare your SQL and call it like so...

```vbs
Dim ds, sql
sql = "EXEC prc_get_report_data "
ds = GetDataSet(sql, "@my_conn")
```

(Note: read the code comments about the connection strings).

The array returned from this is obviously two dimensional zero based, where x = columns, y = rows:

```
ds(x, y)
```

What I tend to do is define constants to cover the column names, matching them to the equivalents in the database...

```
Const COL_ID = 0 'Column 0 is the ID field (note zero based)
Const COL_TITLE = 1 'Title field
Const COL_DESCRIPTION = 2 'Description field
```

...and so on.

Then you can reference them eaasily:

```
If ds(COL_ID, row) = 14 Then
```

Use the `UBound` function to get the extents of the array...

```
Dim row, rows
For rows = 0 To UBound(ds, 2) '2 is the second dimension of the array (note not zero based
    If ds(COL_ID, row) = avalue Then
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Hi, the prob is that this is a big system, with many reports each with many tables - which is why I return multiple recordsets from the stored procs. Using an array GetNoRows() was an idea apart from the huge amount of different column names. I thought a disconnected recordset would have acted similar to an array, but when I go to the "ajax page" to display the data, I get a "Current provider does not support returning multiple recordsets from a single execution." from the recordset in the Session on Session("Data").NextRecordset call (after outputting the 1st recordset)